# What is the nBits field in the CBlockHeader class?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, difficulty, proof-of-work, block-header, c++

In the source code for the [`CBlockHeader`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/306ccd4927a2efe325c8d84be1bdb79edeb29b04/src/primitives/block.h#L14-L65) class, there is a field called `nBits`.

```
/** Nodes collect new transactions into a block, hash them into a hash tree,
 * and scan through nonce values to make the block's hash satisfy proof-of-work
 * requirements.  When they solve the proof-of-work, they broadcast the block
 * to everyone and the block is added to the block chain.  The first transaction
 * in the block is a special one that creates a new coin owned by the creator
 * of the block.
 */
class CBlockHeader
{
public:
    // header
    int32_t nVersion;
    uint256 hashPrevBlock;
    uint256 hashMerkleRoot;
    uint32_t nTime;
    uint32_t nBits;
    uint32_t nNonce;
```

As far as I searched in the code, I didn't found any comment for this field. But I saw the [`CheckBlockHeader`](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/306ccd4927a2efe325c8d84be1bdb79edeb29b04/src/validation.cpp#L3367) function using the `nBits` field to check proof of work of the block. So I interpret that it's a representation of the difficulty for the block.

```
static bool CheckBlockHeader(const CBlockHeader& block, BlockValidationState& state, const Consensus::Params& consensusParams, bool fCheckPOW = true)
{
    // Check proof of work matches claimed amount
    if (fCheckPOW && !CheckProofOfWork(block.GetHash(), block.nBits, consensusParams))
        return state.Invalid(BlockValidationResult::BLOCK_INVALID_HEADER, "high-hash", "proof of work failed");

    return true;
}
```

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **I interpret that it's a representation of the difficulty for the block. ... Is my understanding correct?**

Yes, it is a compact representation of the network target for that block. The target being a kind of inverse of the difficulty.

- [How is difficulty stored in blocks](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty#How_is_difficulty_stored_in_blocks.3F)
- [Is there a rationale for the compact representation of the target?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/57567/13866)